# Where to put custom plugins? custom/plugins or custom/static-plugins in Shopware 6.5

Tags: composer-php, shopware6

This is similar to the question [Shopware 6: What is the usage or benefit of the custom/static-plugins folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73567306/shopware-6-what-is-the-usage-or-benefit-of-the-custom-static-plugins-folder) but in Shopware 6.5 also custom/plugins is added as as src in composer.json and so I am specifically asking about Shopware 6.5

```
    "repositories": {
        "shopware-packages": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.shopware.com"
        },
        "0": {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "custom/plugins/*",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        },
        "1": {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "custom/plugins/*/packages/*",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "custom/static-plugins/*",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        }
    },
```

So I think all both folders are now managed via composer.

What's the recommendation where to put the plugins specifically developer for a project?

And what if you receive a ZIP file from a 3rd party vendor that does not provide a composer repository.

Whats the purpose to have this different folders as of Shopware 6.5 ?

Answer (score 5):

As a rule of thumb I would say that `custom/plugins` should be reserved for third party plugins, usually obtained through the community store, comparable to a `vendor` directory. This just isn't strictly enforced. All plugins can now be managed through composer, as plugins obtained through the store can now have composer dependencies as well.

Comment: How does this reflect in the plugin's table? I moved the plugins to a composer based installation, but the plugin table is still having the path in custom/plugins folder. Any ideas?